# JSF 2 Validation Options

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2 and Primefaces. But I now need to do some more complex validation, specifically cross-field validation and perhaps some validation involving expression language (so I can do conditional validation in my xhtml pages).

I don't think I can do these with my current setup, but I've been reading about various other addons that I could be using such as:

- Seam
- ExtVal
- JSR303

Was just wondering what the most recommended approach was. Does ExtVal need MyFaces as a pre-requisite? And if so, will MyFaces conflict with PrimeFaces?

I've experimented a bit with different jars and run into what look like a few conflicts so appreciate any feedback.

[Update]
As per my comment I went with OmniFaces which was just a case of downloading the jar file and then adding the namespaces to my page:

```
...
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
...
```

And then I used this as a test case (to make sure password and confirmPassword are both the same, but only when one of them has a value). This solves both my 'issues' very easily.

```
<o:validateEqual id="equal" components="password confirmPassword" disabled="#{editUserAdminController.user.password != '' || editUserAdminController.user.confirmPassword}"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: JSF can use an implementation of `JSR303` in case one is provided by the application/server. Cross-field validation is a bit tricky but definitely can be done with the tech availabe.

You may also want to take a look at the [OmniFaces library](http://omnifaces.org) - it features cross-field validation among many other useful things and is not tied to a particular JSF framework.

Comment: Your first statement is not entirely correct. JSF itself doesn't use JSR303 at all for default validation such as `required="true"`, `<f:validateSomething>`, etc, but JSF is just able to recognize its presence in the webapp and delegate validation to it. The specific JSR303 implementation used is not specific to JSF, but to the webapp or servletcontainer. I.e. JSR303 is completely independent from JSF.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this guys. I went down the OmniFaces route and it works well. Very easy to get running too. Whoever wrote that did a good job ;-)